# Python: leaderboard

Tags: python, file, csv, search

I have been asked to design a leader board,

This is what I tried

```
def leader():

    file = open ("res.txt","r")
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    print (("{:20s}{:20s}{:20s}{:20s}".format("\nPlayer","Matches played","Won","Lost")))
    won = 100

    for r in reader:
        won = won-1
        if r[2] == str(won):
           print (("{:20s}{:20s}{:20s}{:20s}".format(r[0],r[1],r[2],r[3])))



    file.close()
```

My csv file looks like this

```
Leeroy,19,7,12
Jenkins,19,8,11
Tyler,19,0,19
Napoleon Wilson,19,7,12
Big Boss,19,7,12
Game Dude,19,5,14
Macho Man,19,3,16
Space Pirate,19,6,13
Billy Casper,19,7,12
Otacon,19,7,12
Big Brother,19,7,12
Ingsoc,19,5,14
Ripley,19,5,14
M'lady,19,4,15
Einstein100,19,8,11
Dennis,19,5,14
Esports,19,8,11
RNGesus,19,7,12
Kes,19,9,10
Magnitude,19,6,13
```

I wish for it to display the person with the most wins first, can you help?

Comment: You can try reading the whole file into memory first in the form of a list and then apply `sorted()` on it with appropriate parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try slurping the file into a list:

```
all_rows = list(reader)
```

Then sort all the rows on the key of most wins:

```
sorted_rows = sorted(all_rows, key=(lambda row: row[2]), reverse=True)
```

You might want to stack several sorts, or define a more complex key, so that you can enforce ordering within equal numbers of wins (for example, 7 wins of 8 plays is better than 7 wins of 100 plays).

Comment: What does key = lambda do?

Comment: A [*lambda expression*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=lambda#lambda-expressions) is basically an in-line function definition. It creates a function that returns whatever expression comes after the `lambda` keyword.

Answer (score -1):

```
keys = ["Player","Matches played","Won","Lost"]

# read file
with open("res.txt") as f:
    content = f.readlines()
# you may also want to remove whitespace characters like `\n` at the end of each line and 
# split it by ',' then form a dictionary out of it 
content = [dict(zip(keys,x.strip().split(','))) for x in content]
# sort the above list of dicts in decreasing orde.
final_result = sorted(content, key=lambda k: k['Won'], reverse=True)

print final_result# sorted By score
# first element is the one with highest Won value
print final_result[0] # highest Won
```